# How to put element over an hover CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, breadcrumbs

I'm using a bootstrap arrow breadcrumb. The following pictures will explain better than me :

Breadcrumb with normal/hover/active element :

[image: Breadcrumb]

Breadcrumb issue, arrow is hiding when active and hover element are closer :

[image: Breadcrumb issue]

I want to keep arrows everytime, i tried z-index but it's not working :/

Hope you understand, thx for help.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".btn-breadcrumb a" ).click(function() {
            $(".btn-breadcrumb a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
```

```css
 .btn-breadcrumb a{
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .btn-breadcrumb a:hover {
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .btn-breadcrumb a.active {
        background-color: #95A5A6;
        color: #fff;
    }

    #breadcrumb_sauvegarde {
        background-color: #d9534f;
        color: #fff;
    }

    #breadcrumb_widget .btn-group{
        display: flex;
    }

    #breadcrumb_widget .btn-breadcrumb .btn {
        flex-grow: 1;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

    /** Triangle Breadcrumb **/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -22.4px;
        left: 100%;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    /** Triangle Breadcrumb **/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):before {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: 1px;
        margin-top: -22.4px;
        left: 100%;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    /**Spacing **/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn {
        padding:12px 24px 12px 48px;
    }
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn:first-child {
        padding:12px 12px 12px 20px;
    }
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn:last-child {
        padding:12px 36px 12px 48px;
    }

    /** /////////////////////////// bouton triangle pour faire apparaitre le breadcrumb en flèche //////////////////////// **/

    /*couleur de fond du triangle*/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
        border-left: 40px solid #fff;
    }
    /*couleur de fond du triangle hover*/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
        border-left: 40px solid #ecf0f1;
    }
    /*couleur de fond du triangle active*/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active:not(:last-child):after {
        border-left: 40px solid #95A5A6;
    }
    /*couleur de fond du triangle sur active hover*/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active:hover:not(:last-child):after {
        border-left: 40px solid #95A5A6;
    }
    /*couleur des bordures du triangle*/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before {
        border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
    }
    /*couleur des bordures du triangle sur hover*/
    .btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
        border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="breadcrumb_widget">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb ">
                <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_configuration" class="btn btn-default active">1. Configuration</a>
                <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_formulaire" class="btn btn-default">2. Formulaire</a>
                <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_preview" class="btn btn-default">3. Preview</a>
                <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_sauvegarde" class="btn btn-default">4. Sauvegarder</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a z-index issue...perhaps trying not using 999 it's unnecessarily large. I've rarely had to use more than 2

Comment: Hi, it is the same thing with lower z-index.

Comment: Try `z-index:auto` on hover

Comment: Hi, no change with auto ^^. Zuber seems to have a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to set `z-index` for `active` button. check **Added CSS** at
  the bottom of the `css`
- Set `z-index: unset;` to `.btn`. Check **Updated** `css`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".btn-breadcrumb a" ).click(function() {
            $(".btn-breadcrumb a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
```

```css
.btn-breadcrumb a{
font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-breadcrumb a:hover {
z-index: 1;
}

.btn-breadcrumb a.active {
    background-color: #95A5A6;
    color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumb_sauvegarde {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumb_widget .btn-group{
    display: flex;
}

#breadcrumb_widget .btn-breadcrumb .btn {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: unset; /* Update */
}

/** Triangle Breadcrumb **/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22.4px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

/** Triangle Breadcrumb **/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: -22.4px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

/**Spacing **/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn {
    padding:12px 24px 12px 48px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:first-child {
    padding:12px 12px 12px 20px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:last-child {
    padding:12px 36px 12px 48px;
}

/** /////////////////////////// bouton triangle pour faire apparaitre le breadcrumb en flèche //////////////////////// **/

/*couleur de fond du triangle*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 40px solid #fff;
}
/*couleur de fond du triangle hover*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 40px solid #ecf0f1;
}
/*couleur de fond du triangle active*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 40px solid #95A5A6;
}
/*couleur de fond du triangle sur active hover*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active:hover:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 40px solid #95A5A6;
}
/*couleur des bordures du triangle*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before {
    border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
}
/*couleur des bordures du triangle sur hover*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
    border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
}
/*** Added CSS ***/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  id="breadcrumb_widget" >
            <div class="panel panel-default" >
                <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb " >
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_configuration" class="btn btn-default active" >1. Configuration</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_formulaire" class="btn btn-default">2. Formulaire</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_preview" class="btn btn-default">3. Preview</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_sauvegarde" class="btn btn-default">4. Sauvegarder</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Zuber, i test your answer on my own code, something doesnt work. I back to you later. Thx.

Comment: Maybe some of your code is overriding, Please double check

Comment: Yeah, it's work, thx. I added this for the other side .btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover {
    z-index: 4;
}

Comment: Yes dude i will, just re-opened to people see the question is not close. The question still available because i have the same issue on other side and i want to know how to fix it. You can test your own code, there is the same issue. Thx

Comment: @vincent please check my updated answer, hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your own styling is being overridden by bootstrap

[image]

Just Add `!important

```css
.btn-breadcrumb a {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-breadcrumb a:hover {
  z-index: 1 !important;
}

.btn-breadcrumb a.active {
  background-color: #95A5A6;
  color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumb_sauvegarde {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumb_widget .btn-group {
  display: flex;
}

#breadcrumb_widget .btn-breadcrumb .btn {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}


/** Triangle Breadcrumb **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -22.4px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}


/** Triangle Breadcrumb **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: -22.4px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}


/**Spacing **/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn {
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 48px;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:first-child {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 20px;
}

.btn-breadcrumb .btn:last-child {
  padding: 12px 36px 12px 48px;
}


/** /////////////////////////// bouton triangle pour faire apparaitre le breadcrumb en flèche //////////////////////// **/


/*couleur de fond du triangle*/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 40px solid #fff;
}


/*couleur de fond du triangle hover*/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 40px solid #ecf0f1;
}


/*couleur de fond du triangle active*/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 40px solid #95A5A6;
}


/*couleur de fond du triangle sur active hover*/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 40px solid #95A5A6;
}


/*couleur des bordures du triangle*/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
}


/*couleur des bordures du triangle sur hover*/

.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="breadcrumb_widget">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb ">
      <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_configuration" class="btn btn-default active">1. Configuration</a>
      <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_formulaire" class="btn btn-default">2. Formulaire</a>
      <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_preview" class="btn btn-default">3. Preview</a>
      <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_sauvegarde" class="btn btn-default">4. Sauvegarder</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".btn-breadcrumb a" ).click(function() {
            $(".btn-breadcrumb a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
```

```css
.btn-breadcrumb a{
font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-breadcrumb a:hover {
z-index: 1;
}

.btn-breadcrumb a.active {
    background-color: #95A5A6;
    color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumb_sauvegarde {
    background-color: #d9534f;
    color: #fff;
}

#breadcrumb_widget .btn-group{
    display: flex;
}

#breadcrumb_widget .btn-breadcrumb .btn {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

/** Triangle Breadcrumb **/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -22.4px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

/** Triangle Breadcrumb **/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:not(:last-child):before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: -22.4px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

/**Spacing **/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn {
    padding:12px 24px 12px 48px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:first-child {
    padding:12px 12px 12px 20px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .btn:last-child {
    padding:12px 36px 12px 48px;
}

/** /////////////////////////// bouton triangle pour faire apparaitre le breadcrumb en flèche //////////////////////// **/

/*couleur de fond du triangle*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 40px solid #fff;
}
/*couleur de fond du triangle hover*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 40px solid #ecf0f1;
}
/*couleur de fond du triangle active*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 40px solid #95A5A6;
}
/*couleur de fond du triangle sur active hover*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default.active:hover:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left: 40px solid #95A5A6;
}
/*couleur des bordures du triangle*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before {
    border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
}
/*couleur des bordures du triangle sur hover*/
.btn-breadcrumb .btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
    border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  id="breadcrumb_widget" >
            <div class="panel panel-default" >
                <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb " >
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_configuration" class="btn btn-default active" >1. Configuration</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_formulaire" class="btn btn-default">2. Formulaire</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_preview" class="btn btn-default">3. Preview</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_sauvegarde" class="btn btn-default">4. Sauvegarder</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set z-index for .btn descending order.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".btn-breadcrumb a" ).click(function() {
            $(".btn-breadcrumb a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
```

```css
    .btn-breadcrumb a.btn {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 48px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn.active {
  background-color: #95a5a6;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -22.4px;
  left: 100%;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn:not(:last-child):before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 22.4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 22.4px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: -22.4px;
  left: 100%;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn:first-child {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 20px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn:last-child {
  padding: 12px 36px 12px 48px;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 40px solid #fff;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 40px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn.btn-default.active:not(:last-child):after, .btn-breadcrumb a.btn.btn-default.active:hover:not(:last-child):after {
  border-left: 40px solid #95a5a6;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a.btn.btn-default:not(:last-child):before, .btn-breadcrumb a.btn.btn-default:hover:not(:last-child):before {
  border-left: 40px solid #5e595d;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 1) {
  z-index: 4;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 1):after, .btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 1):before {
  z-index: 998;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 1).active {
  z-index: 4;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 1):hover {
  z-index: 4;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 2) {
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 2):after, .btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 2):before {
  z-index: 997;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 2).active {
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 2):hover {
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 3) {
  z-index: 2;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 3):after, .btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 3):before {
  z-index: 996;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 3).active {
  z-index: 2;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 3):hover {
  z-index: 2;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 4) {
  z-index: 1;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 4):after, .btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 4):before {
  z-index: 995;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 4).active {
  z-index: 1;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 4):hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 5) {
  z-index: 0;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 5):after, .btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 5):before {
  z-index: 994;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 5).active {
  z-index: 0;
}
.btn-breadcrumb a:nth-child(n + 5):hover {
  z-index: 0;
}
#breadcrumb_sauvegarde {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  color: #fff;
}
#breadcrumb_widget .btn-group {
  display: flex;
}
#breadcrumb_widget .btn-breadcrumb .btn {
flex-grow: 1;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  id="breadcrumb_widget" >
            <div class="panel panel-default" >
                <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb " >
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_configuration" class="btn btn-default active" >1. Configuration</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_formulaire" class="btn btn-default">2. Formulaire</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_preview" class="btn btn-default">3. Preview</a>
                    <a href="#" id="breadcrumb_sauvegarde" class="btn btn-default">4. Sauvegarder</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```